# jQuery Duplicate Text As You Type and Keep the Cursor Moving

Tags: jquery, text, input, duplicates, keyup

I'm using this jQuery code to duplicate in real time what I type in one input field to another input field. It works; however, when I type a lot in the first field, the cursor keeps going, displaying whatever I'm typing. In the second field, whatever I'm typing gets covered since the cursor doesn't move. How can I keep the text visible up to the latest character typed on the second field as well?

```
$("#text_1").keyup(function() {
    $("#text_2").val( $("#text_1").val() );
})

<label>TEXT 1: </label><input type="text" id="text_1" value=""/>
<br>
<label>TEXT 2: </label><input type="text" id="text_2" value=""/>
```

Here's the JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/d5vkrLve/

Notice that if you type a lot in the first box, you're able to see the newest text because the cursor moves, but in box two, the text doesn't move. You're unable to see the newest text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text in a content element like `span` instead

HTML

```
<label>TEXT 1: </label>
<input type="text" id="text_1" value="" />
<br>
<label>TEXT 2: </label>
<span id="text_2"></span>
```

JS

```
$("#text_1").keyup(function() {
  $("#text_2").text($("#text_1").val());
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d5vkrLve/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: Great answer--this was just what I was looking for. THANK YOU.